# Verificação de base64?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, base64

Estou fazendo uma aplicação de emails(HapiJS) e descobri que alguns emails tem o texto dele codificado para base64, porém outros não.

Nessa minha aplicação precisarei receber emails de todos os serviços(Gmail, Hotmail, ...) e preciso fazer um método para verificar se o texto está em base64 ou não, para somente aí encaminhar para decodificação ou direto para o cliente.

Já procurei bastante e até agora não consegui achar nada que funcionasse 100% como eu preciso, e como sou novato em programação, ainda não possuo conhecimento suficiente para descobrir sozinho como fazer isso...

Código que estou usando para tentar verificar:

```
let base64 = /^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$/;

        let isBase64Valid = base64.test(mail.text); // base64Data is the base64 string

        if (isBase64Valid) {   
            // true if base64 formate
            console.log('base64');
        } else {
            // false if not in base64 formate
            console.log('String');
        }
```

Comment: Isso ajuda? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-the-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not

Comment: Ajudou bastante, esclareceu muita coisa, mas ainda não resolveu o problema...

Comment: Então talvez seja uma boa hora para [edit] a pergunta e incrementá-la. Você já deve ter testado algum código, então coloque-o na pergunta e indique quais foram os erros ou dificuldades encontradas.

Comment: Usei alguns códigos do link que você me passou eles funcionam mas não corretamente, pois até os emails que estão em base64 ele está identificando como se não estivesse, e vou editar a pergunta e adicionar código nela para esclarecer melhor a dúvida

Comment: Todo o e-mail está em base64 ou somente parte dele?

Comment: O texto dele está em base64 e se tiver alguma imagem ela também é convertida para base64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As strings em base64 tem apenas os caracteres de a-z, A-Z, 0-9,'+','/' e '=' ou seja, se existir qualquer caracter que não sejam estes, como por exemplo um espaço ' ', então essa string não está em base64. Esse é o teste que deve ser feito por regex.

Tente alterar o Regex para este aqui:
**^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$**

Para codificar e decodificar utilize as funções `btoa()` para codificar e `atob()` para decodificar. Segue referência para as funções: 
[JS base64 Encode and Decode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

Comment: Muito obrigado Alexandre...

Comment: Desculpe a opinião más não acredito que este regex esteja correto pois ele valida qualquer conjunto com comprimento múltiplo de quatro ex: **"regexnaofunciona"**, **"hoje"**, **"errado+tanto+faz"**... o correto seria envelopar em um `try\catch` o retorno da função `atob` usando a possível string encodada. Isso de fato definiria se a string foi encodada em base64

Answer (score 1):

Usando `javascript` a abordagem mais correta de verificar se uma dada `{String}` foi (está) codificada em **base64** no front-end é envelopando em um bloco `try\catch` o retorno da função `atob()` em comparação ao próprio retorno encodado visto que, a `VM` do `javascript` do navegador já lançará uma exceção no caso de falha.

Alguns exemplos aqui da comunidade StackOverflow (portuguesa, inglesa) dizem que a seguinte abordagem é o mais correto:

```
function isBase64(str) {
    try {
        return atob(str) ? true : false
    } catch(e) {
        return false
    }
}
```

Contudo esta abordagem está incorreta visto que o seguinte exemplo retornaria um **"falso-positivo"**:

```
isBase64('jgjhgj hg') // true
```

Quando na verdade o retorno do exemplo acima usando `atob()` seria:

```
console.log(atob('jgjhgj hg')) // "á8`"
```

---

> A abordagem front-end mais correta

O correto seria "encodar" a "decodificação" e compara-lá a entrada assim:

```
function isBase64(str) {
    try {
        return btoa(atob(str)) === str ? true : false
    } catch(e) {
        return false
    }
}
```

Deste modo refuta-se os casos de **"falsos-positivos"**:

```
isBase64('jgjhgj hg') // false
```

---

> No back-end (NodeJs)

Não exitem funções nativas em **NodeJS** como `btoa()` ou `atob()` por isso é muito comum o uso de módulos de terceiros ou o uso de `Buffer` para se chegar ao mesmo resultado.

É importante ressaltar que nem todas as bibliotecas de terceiros reportam **"exceções"** ou fazem uma comparação contra a entrada e assim é fácil passar por **"falsos-positivos"**.

O seguinte exemplo utiliza `Buffer` para encodar e decodificar além de verificar contra a entrada:

```
function atob(str) {
    return new Buffer(str, 'base64').toString('binary');
}

function btoa(str) {
    let buffer;
    if ( str instanceof Buffer ) {
        buffer = str
    } else {
        buffer = new Buffer(str.toString(), 'binary')
    }
    return buffer.toString('base64')
}

function isBase64(str) {
    try {
         return btoa(atob(str)) === str ? true : false
    } catch(ex) {
        false
    }
}
```

Testando é possível perceber que não reporta **"falsos-positivos"**:

```
console.log(isBase64('SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh')) // true

console.log(isBase64('jgjhgj hg')) // false
```

---

> O uso de RegExp (questão opinativa)

Se não é possível creditar que a entrada (origem) da `{String}` de fato seja encodada (e por isto a necessidade de verificação) nem sempre o uso de `RegExp` deve ser entendido como "a melhor opção" o seguinte exemplo expressa esta questão:

```
function isBase64(str) {
    return /^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$/.test(str)
}

isBase64('SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh') // true

isBase64('jgjhgj hg') // false

isBase64("regexnaofunciona") // true

isBase64("hoje") // true

isBase64("errado+tanto+faz") // true
```

A expressão acima é falha pois valida qualquer `{String}` com comprimento de 4 ou múltiplo de 4.

Vale ressaltar que se não é possível afirmar que a `{String}` de entrada de fato foi encodada em **base64** não existe garantia que o `RegExp` acima não valide-a formando assim um **"falso-positivo"**.

Comment: Excelente resposta, buscando abstrair os `falsos-positivos` coisa que acontece com bastante frequência principalmente falando de **javascript**.